# Is there a way to classify groups up to isomorphism?

Tags: group-theory

Is there a nice way to classify/decompose finite groups? The classification of finite simple groups lets us determine all possible composition factors in the composition series but there are nonisomorphic groups with the same composition factors in their respective composition series e.g. $ C_{6} $ and $ D_6 $. If not, is there an analogous theory for a group to be 'completely reducible'?

Answer (score 11):

There has been a lot of research on this topic! I would recommend you look at the article

A millennium project: constructing small groups, Hans Ulrich Besche, Bettina Eick, E.A. O'Brien, Internat. J. Algebra Comput. 12 (5), 623-644, 2002.

You can download it from O'Brien's webpage:

http://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~obrien/papers.php

Comment: That pdf looks like a ransom note.

Comment: @anon, what do you mean?

Answer (score 8):

There is another way to approach this: in 1940 Philip Hall introduced *isoclinism*, an equivalence relation on groups coarser than isomorphism (being isomorphic implies being isoclinic, but not vice versa). The concept of isoclinism was introduced to classify p-groups, although the concept is applicable to all groups. Isoclinism can be extended to *isologism*, which is similar to isoclinism, but then w.r.t. a variety of groups. There exists a vast literature on isoclinism and isologism.

Comment: for what its worth, the number of isoclinism and even isologism classes is asymptotically about the same as isomorphism.  So this is just barely a coarser relation.

Comment: Thanks for your remark, but what is *asymptotically about same*? Could you please explain?

Comment: if you count groups of order at most n there are between n^{2/27 mu(n)^2+O(mu(n)) and n^{2/27 mu(n)^2 + O(mu(n)^1.5)} up to isomorphism, n=p^k is the lower bound and thought to be the tight bound.  Of p-groups isoclinism class count n^{2/27 mu(n)^2 +O(mu(n))).  mu(p_1^e_1 … p_m^e_m ) = max_i e_i

Comment: Ah yes, interesting. Is there a paper that proves this? Marcus du Sautoy?

Comment: No Marcus's enumerative work is usually on what congruence classes of primes do what, this is Simon Blackburn I believe, you can get it for p odd easily though by looking at class 2 exponent p, there isoclinism=isomorphism and those groups by Higman (1960) achieve the lower bound (p=2 needs slight modification of course)

Comment: OK clear, thanks for the info and again for your remark, will check Blackburn.